# Не собирается проект CLR

Tags: c++-cli, clr

Создаю пустой проект CLR.Создаю форму UI и точку входа main.Но и MyForm.cpp и в MyForm.h в самом начале,около 1 символа инклюидов подчеркивание и пишет:

> Ошибка(активно)   E1696   ошибка в командной строке : не удается открыть метаданные файл "System.Runtime.dll" KeyGen  C : \Users\Encryptme\Desktop\KeyGen\KeyGen\MyForm.cpp   1
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У вашей проблемы может быть множество причин:

1. Проверьте, что при создании вы используете шаблон проекта .Net Framework, а не .Net Core

[image: Интерфейс создания проекта]

2. Убедитесь, что установлена точка входа и целевая система в настройках проекта: Свойства конфигурации -> Компоновщик
3. Так как ошибка E1696 часто связана с предварительно откомпилированными заголовками попробуйте отключить предварительно откомпилированные заголовки или установить их создание в настройках проекта: Свойства конфигурации -> C/C++ . Также можете добавить файл вручную. (следует отметить, что в современной версии VS 2019 используется автоматически создаваемый файл pch.h)
4. Убедитесь, что установлен корректный набор инструментов платформы в настройках проекта: Свойства конфигурации -> Общие.
5. Убедитесь что вставляете правильный код. Пример:

```
#include "Название заголовка формы.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Название_проекта::Название_класса_формы form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

6. Если не находите решение, также попробуйте:

   - открыть и закрыть проект
   - удалить папку ipch и открыть проект
   - пересобрать проект
   - перепроверить решение (меню правой кнопки мыши)
   - переустановить Пакет инструментов C++
   - переустановить или обновить Visual studio

*Надеюсь вам помогло!*

[image: Конфигурация проекта]

Comment: А разве core умеет плюсы?

Comment: Умеет https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/an-update-on-cpp-cli-and-dotnet-core/

Comment: @Qwertiy оно умеет, но только для Windows. Но ошибка в данном вопросе с этим никак не связана, это древний баг еще как минимум с VS 2015: http://streletzcoder.ru/lechim-vizualnyiy-redaktor-dlya-windows-forms-v-visual-c-2015/